# checking for my local notification that was not delivered when mobile was dead

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I have created a local notification which will fire a notification three times a day.
In afternoon user mobile was dead ,now he will not be able to see his afternoon notification.
By which method i can know that which notification was not delivered and delivering it when user iPhone become on.

Comment: By keeping track of what notifications you've registered, and which ones you've handled.

Comment: please can you elaborate it thanks in advance